# Some refault Rating for Woo-Commerce product in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rating

Too explain more, I have a shopping website where many of the products are not rated but I would like to show some default rating like 3 stars or 5 stars for each product which is not rated. The purpose is to show ratings for each products in any possible way. Is it possible? Please let me know how can I do it in the best easiest way.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

With some search, Here is what I found :

[PHP Method WC_Product::set_average_rating, woocommerce Code Examples](http://hotexamples.com/examples/-/WC_Product/set_average_rating/php-wc_product-set_average_rating-method-examples.html)

So, I suppose you could do something like this :

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $count = $product->get_rating_count();
    if (!$count) {
        $average = 0.65;
    }
    $product->set_average_rating($average);
    $data_store = $product->get_data_store();
    $data_store->update_average_rating($product);
}
```

/!\ not tested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where should I use this, I mean in which file? Do I need to copy this to functions.php?